# For-loop first iteration over generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator which gives me "chunks" of a pandas dataframe. I save the chunks into a csv file.

For the first "chunk" I want to disable "mode='a'" as I want to overwrite the file if one exists already, the following chunks should be added to the newly created file.

For now I have solved it with a variable outside the loop: "first".

```
first = True
for chunk in generator:
    if first:
        chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';')
        first = False
    else:
        chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';', mode='a', header=False)
```

Is there a more elegant way to treat the first element of a generator differently than the rest?

---

I have found the following code to treat the first object in a list differently, however, it does not work for the generator-object.

```
seq= something.get()
foob( seq[0] )
for member in seq[1:]:
    foo( member )
```

Trying to implement the code of the list for the generator gives me a TypeError ('generator' object is not subscriptable):

```
generator[0].to_csv(filename, sep=';')
for chunk in generator[1:]:
    chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';', mode='a', header=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next). This way you don't have the overhead of the repetitive `if` check (as neglectable as it may be) every iteration:

```
first = next(generator)
first.to_csv(filename, sep=';')
for chunk in generator:  # will start from the second element
    chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';', mode='a', header=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(generator):
    chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';', mode=('w' if i == 0 else 'a'), header=(i == 0))
```

Alternatively with a helper variable:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(generator):
    first = i == 0
    chunk.to_csv(filename, sep=';', mode=('w' if first else 'a'), header=first)
```

Comment: While I love "one-line solutions", I think I will go with "next" as suggested by DeepSpace. The files are quite big and I have a lot of chunks, which would mean a lot of if-checks.

Comment: The if-checks are a red herring. They will contribute precisely *zero* to overall running time, no matter how many chunks you have.

Comment: Disk IO is the slowest thing in this scenario, inbetween writing chunks to disk your program will have billions of CPU cycles free to do any amount of if checks.